# Marketing Cloud pushing notifications to external app. How?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, mobilepush

I wonder if anyone has any pointers or good ideas on this. 
I am researching best way to use Mobile connect, to send push notifications to an external ios or android app.

I guess the app needs to include Marketing Cloud sdk ... best practice, anyone?

Comment: could you verify if you are researching mobile connect? (which is SMS communication) or Mobile Push (app integration, as Brian indicates)

Answer (score 4):

The Marketing Cloud SDK would be the right way to accomplish this. The setup is simple, both iOS and Android are supported and there are a number of ways for integrating messaging in a broader system.

Docs are here:

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/

and

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/

Best of luck,

Brian M. Criscuolo

Senior Mobile Engineer, Salesforce Marketing Cloud